# Bypass option for winget for "no store account found"

Tags: powershell, winget

I'm trying to install sysinternals for our computers remotely, but when attempting to install with `winget install sysinternals --accept-source-agreements --accept-package-agreements` I'm getting "**Verifying/Requesting package acquisition failed: no store account found**"

When trying `winget install --help` I get the following options:

```
Windows Package Manager v1.1.12653
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Installs the selected package, either found by searching a configured source or directly from a manifest. By default, the query must case-insensitively match the id, name, or moniker of the package. Other fields can be used by passing their appropriate option.

usage: winget install [[-q] <query>] [<options>]

The following arguments are available:
  -q,--query                   The query used to search for a package

The following options are available:
  -m,--manifest                The path to the manifest of the package
  --id                         Filter results by id
  --name                       Filter results by name
  --moniker                    Filter results by moniker
  -v,--version                 Use the specified version; default is the latest version
  -s,--source                  Find package using the specified source
  --scope                      Select install scope (user or machine)
  -e,--exact                   Find package using exact match
  -i,--interactive             Request interactive installation; user input may be needed
  -h,--silent                  Request silent installation
  --locale                     Locale to use (BCP47 format)
  -o,--log                     Log location (if supported)
  --override                   Override arguments to be passed on to the installer
  -l,--location                Location to install to (if supported)
  --force                      Override the installer hash check
  --accept-package-agreements  Accept all license agreements for packages
  --header                     Optional Windows-Package-Manager REST source HTTP header
  --accept-source-agreements   Accept all source agreements during source operations

More help can be found at: https://aka.ms/winget-command-install
```

I've tried different options, when doing `winget install --help` like --silent, --interactive, or --override, but to no avail.

I can go into the Microsoft Store directly to install it and it asks me if I want to sign in or use "No Thanks" to install, which then works, but this isn't what I'm intending to do, I don't want to go to each machine to do this. I could probably try the other method of installing through Powershell from here https://serverfault.com/questions/1018220/how-do-i-install-an-app-from-windows-store-using-powershell, but this again, is not what I'm intended.

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about this, but if it helps, here's the source (line 87) https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/1a6a60fddd95480d4f1d9bb1c9abbab84f3cc4b4/src/AppInstallerCLICore/Workflows/MSStoreInstallerHandler.cpp

Answer (score 5):

This isn't supported yet (as of January 2022). There is an open issue at GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1585

Edit:
This bug was fixed and is available in the Windows Package Manager 1.3-preview release. It will be a part of the 1.3 release (as of June 2022)

Windows Package Manager [releases at Github](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases).

Comment: How do you get the preview release? -- The latest release on github is the full release of 1.2.x.

Answer (score 4):

open the MS Store and setting. toggle purchase login to on.

Comment: This toggle requires a login to the Microsoft Store. I can install from the store directly and ask it to not use an account, and it installs just fine. I don't want to do this for each computer separately.

Comment: I was logged in with my work account and needed to log in with my personal account for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

To download the experimental version where a store account is not required for free applications, go to the [github page](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.1741) for winget-cli. Here you can download the .msixbundle (anything above v1.3 should be good).